# How to create connection between two KVM private network

Tags: networking, network-programming, kvm, ikvm

How can a create a connection between two KVM private network communicate each other?

I have two KVM node. In both sever there is a bridge connection for the interface br0 with network 10.10.5.0/28 and in other KVM node there is a bridge connection for the interface br0 with network 20.20.5.0/28 . I can create a VM from both interface. But, how can I make a connection so that 10.10.5.0/28 can be reachable to 20.20.5.0/28 ?

Any suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: You need a router. The entire point of a router is to route packets between different networks. Bridges bridge frames in the same network, but to send packets to a different network requires a router.

Comment: Can we do it from vlan?

Comment: To get from one VLAN to another requires a router. Simply enable routing in your server and configure it. It is not all that difficult, but it certainly does not belong on a programming site.

Comment: How can we enbale the routing in both the KVM? As I need to provide the route between both the node.

Comment: The routing happens in the host server, but this is not a programming question, so you are asking on the wrong SE site.

Comment: So where should I ask , any suggestion?

Comment: For your personal device, [su] may be the place. If this is in a business environment, then [sf] may be able to help, but they will close if it is not in a business.

Comment: Thank you @RonMaupin